# Adding document type to XML using XDeclaration

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I am trying to add an XDeclaration to an XML document like so:

```
XDocument doc = new XDocument();
XDeclaration dc = new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "no");
XNamespace ns = "http://www.foo.com/bar";

doc.Add(dc);
```

However, I get the following error:

> Non white space characters cannot be added to content.

If I take away the XDeclaration line the code works fine, where am I going wrong?

Comment: _Where_ do you get the error? What's the stack trace?

Comment: I'm probably going to get banned from Stack Overflow for this, but how do I view the Stack Trace? Even a link with information on this would be helpful. Thanks...*braces self for instant ban*

Comment: No, you won't.  It's in the `View Exception Detail` link in the exception popup.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to set the declaration like this, not with `.Add` like you tried:

```
doc.Declaration = dc;
```

Or it can be set when [instantiating the xDocument with this constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338517.aspx)

Comment: Just to add, I did this and used doc.Save instead of doc.ToString to save my XML file. When using doc.ToString, the Declaration didn't come through. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`XDeclaration` is not a [valid content](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb943882.aspx) of `XDocument`. Use instead property [Declaration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.declaration.aspx).